# Sending Mails to more than 100 recipients with Google App Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I coded a little script, that forwards mails to a mailing list (with ~80 recipients)

The problem is the 100/day quota limit ([as seen here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas))
The script would be pretty useless if I can forward 1 and a half emails per day...
Can I somehow increase that limit?

If not, do you have any other ideas on how to forward the mails to ~80 recipients without this limit?!

Comment: People and organizations in general tend to dislike spam, hence the limit.

Comment: I know thanks... doesn't answer my question though...
Also: Google says, the limits **"are provided solely to assist you in testing scripts"**

Answer (score 1):

Google explicitly doesn't want you using Apps Script for this kind of thing, which is why the limits are low.

You should use a service designed to send mass emails and forward to that from your apps script.

For example, create a Google Group with your 80+ recipients, then forward the emails to that Group.  Or look into other mail-blast tools such as Mailchimp.